# Since photons do not experience time (nor distance in that case), why did Einstein think it was "spooky action at a distance"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, epr-experiment

A photon travels at c, so it experiences no time or distance. I imagine from the photon's perspective, it's rather just like a simple dot on some kind of 4D manifold. So it begs the question of why *wouldn't* a photon's state be a sort of omnipresent thing that, if you change it, changes wherever (and even, whenever) the photon is? How do physicists justify the idea that something about a photon can ever change, seeing as how time does not pass for it?

Comment: "Spooky action at a distance" happens to all particles, not just photons.

Comment: Does it happen to any particles that aren't electrons or positrons and that don't have any gluons in them?

Answer (score 2):

It happens to photons and other particles. Even for photons when they separate they are same distance and time away from each other, and for an observer time and distance traveled are real and can be measured.

You can create a pair of photons which are entangled by the way they were created in some physical process, like the anihilation of otHer particles or emission of photons from them. When they travel away from each other at speed c wrt an observer say at their common starting point. They may be created so that one has horizontal polarization and one vertical say. But the process is random and which one goes one way vs the other way is random. The observer does not know which is which. Call this observer A, and the two polarizations H and V

Let's say there are two other observers, each 300,000 Kms away from the central observer. That's 1 light second away from the central observer. Call those two far away observers B and C.

The spooky action at a distance is that if one second after they were emitted at A's position, observer B can measure the polarization of the arriving photon, and if he measured H the photon at C will be forced to be measured as V. And viceversa.

So simply put, the spooky action at a distance is that whatever polarization one is the other one can not be.

Clearly not that spooky in this case, just straight physics. Einstein and others created other conceptual examples that were more spooky. The classical example is the EPR paradox, a similar setting to what I described above, and questioning how things separated by great distances can in any way affect the measurement of something far away. Since they cannot be in causal contact from so far away he saw it as a spooky action at a distance

Note that time and distance have passed. 1 sec and 300,000 Kms, as seen by B and C (yes, their clocks had to be pre synchronized with A's), no problem because they are in the same inertial frames of reference. Time and distance are the same for all 3 observers. The photon states did change, they are at different positions than they were 1 sec before.

See the EPR paradox in Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox

Any particles that are created together as a result of some elementary interaction or interaction of other particles will be entangled; it just means that their quantum properties obeys some laws and are correlated, and as long as they don't interact with anything else they will have those correlated properties. It can be done with protons and neutrons, and other particles, as well as electrons. It can happen to muons and pions and quarks. When they start interacting with other particles they will be said to have decohered, not coherent with the particle they were entangled with in the first place.